# Add point system after pay with paypal

Tags: php, node.js, paypal

I have a website that use can buy points. I use paypal for payment. My method is this. 
- After paypal sucess redirect to a success?point=100
- In success page I will **add point to user** base on the point variable.
- But like this user can **type direct in url or refresh** the page. It also add point.

My question is how to prevent user type direct in url or refresh

Server language: PHP, Nodejs

Comment: The safest way is to use server-side code to add the points to the database.  The POST method is safer than the GET (url) method, but still easily spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the redirect page to notify the user that their payment has been completed, but **do not** take any action from that page.

Instead, set up a [PayPal IPN (Instant Payment Notification)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) endpoint. PayPal will make a request to this endpoint with specific parameters to securely notify you that a payment has been received; use that to update the user's balance. Note that this notification may arrive either before *or* after the user views the redirect page, depending on how quickly their browser redirects and how long it takes PayPal to verify the payment and call your endpoint.